# VerbatimOut crashes on special symbols inside if-then-else

Tags: verbatim, fancyvrb

This code compiles just fine with lualatex, xelatex, and pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{VerbatimOut}{x.txt}
^^_
\end{VerbatimOut}
\end{document}
```

However, this one compiles only with pdflatex and fails with lualatex and xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\openin 15=x.txt
\ifeof 15
\begin{VerbatimOut}{x.txt}
^^_
\end{VerbatimOut}
\fi
\end{document}
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.7 ^^_
```

How do I make it compile with *all* latexs?

Comment: I don't have a computer to test, but for my package robust-externalize, I used xsim to write the verbatim text in a dummy file, then I read it again with LaTeX3, and later I write the content back to the good file conditionally (but in my case I did more complex processing of the input so it makes more sense). That's a bit dirty but at least it should work. Otherwise, have you checked also with xsim if you get the same error?

Comment: I'm not sure what would be the purpose of writing onto a file that's currently open for reading. Can you please explain your aim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have a bit of a problem here. `^^_` is invalid input in luatex and if it sees it, it will complain. The problem is not the `\VerbatimOut`, but that if `x.txt` already exists you are in a false branch, luatex skips over the contents but nevertheless sees the `^^_`.

E.g. this here compiles without problems:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{
\iftrue 
\catcode`\^=11
\catcode`\_=11
^^_
\fi
}

\end{document}
```

but if you change to `\iffalse` it errors

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{
\iffalse 
\catcode`\^=11
\catcode`\_=11
^^_
\fi
}

\end{document}
```

And in your example both the writing and checking the file works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{VerbatimOut}{x.txt}
^^_
\end{VerbatimOut}
\openin 15=x.txt
\ifeof 15
aaa
\fi
\end{document}
```

but as soon as you replace the `aaa` by `^^_` it errors. So you will have to avoid such input in false branches.

Comment: Is it possible to store a verbatim content in a latex3 string without writting it in a temporary file first?